# react multiple binding but only for one side

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have 2 inputs the first one has setState like

```
<input onChange={e => this.setState({ price: e.target.value })} />
```

and the second one I do

```
<input value={this.state.price} />
```

This will do binding. Updating the first one will update the second one. But I want to modify the second one without dependent on the first one. I did find one solution; to use `defaultValue` instead of `value`. But the problem is input one no longer updates input two on `onKeyPress` events.

Comment: If two input will share same state, it will be dependent . Either you need 2 different state. Or  state of type object or Arry.

Comment: what about having different state properties (state={input1: "", input2:""}) for each input and updating the other input state property only when the first input property changes?

Comment: not clear, lets say you entered some text in first one 'abc', 'abc' will populate in second, now you want to change second lets say 'def', then if you change first one to 'xyz' what you want in second ? you just want the initial value of second one from first or something else ?